# Are there different folder types in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2010, we have a folder in App_Code that isn't recognizing some of our web_references, and I noticed that in the last few days the folder's (CommonSignUp) appearance in Solution Explorer has changed from grey to yellow.  Can someone tell me what the two folder types are and if there is a way to convert from one type to another.  Yes, grasping at straws here, but I think something has happened to this folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders). Also you can browse project files with text editor and take a look how the folders looks there.